# Выборка из базы данных с сортировкой в yii2

Tags: sql, yii2

Начал изучать yii2, сделал выборку из базы данных

```
        $requests = $query->orderBy('time')
        ->offset($pagination->offset)
        ->limit($pagination->limit)
        ->where($where)
        ->all();
```

Выводятся все и если есть переменная `$where` то выводит только с совпадающие строки, что очевидно. А хотелось бы сделать чтобы при допустим значении `$where = "Тест5"` записи с полем равным `"Тест5"` выводились первые, а дальше `Тест1, Тест2, ..., ТестN`. Может каким-нибудь штатным средством yii2 можно сделать такую сортировку или проще запросом к базе?
Данные выводятся просто

```
<?php foreach ($requests as $request): ?>
<li>
    <?= Html::encode("{$request->form_name} ({$request->contacts})") ?>:
    <?= $request->status ?>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если этот порядок постоянный, я бы предложил создать поле sort, в котором хранить последовательность, а если поле sort не подходит, то не вижу проблемы сначала выбрать первый элемент, а затем всю последовательность без выбранного элемента. Например, первым запросом выбираем только "Тест5", а вторым запросом "Тест1, Тест2, ..., ТестN" без "Тест5".

Comment: Да, была такая идея, просто с запросами в yii2 немного туго понимаю. получается через union сделать второй запрос?

Comment: зачем union, просто в два запроса, не вижу смысла объединять в один запрос. просто средствами php сделайте $requests=array_merge($requests,[$request]); и выводите как выводили.